# Generating sum of minterms in java

Tags: java, boolean-expression

How can I generate the sum of minterms (boolean algebra) in java? We can generate sum of minterms throw ANDing with `(X+X')`. The following example explains the algorithm for a function with three variables A,B and C:

```
F(A,B,C)= A + B´*C
        = A*(B+B´) + B´*C
        = A*B + A*B´ + B´*C
        = A*B*(C+C´) + A*B´*(C+C´) + B´*C*(A+A´)
        = A*B*C+A*B*C´+A*B´*C+A*B´*C´+B´*C*A+B´*C*A´
        = A*B*C+A*B*C´+A*B´*C+A*B´*C´+A*B´*C+A´*B´*C
```

The method in java looks like this:

```
String generateSumOfMinterms(String termsOfTheFunction, String variables){}


// Examples for functions with 2 variables A,B
generateSumOfMinterms("A", "A,B"){

//The result should looks like this
return "A*B+A*B'";
}
generateSumOfMinterms("A+B'", "A,B"){

//The result should looks like this (repeated terms are ok for example A*B')
return "A*B+A*B'+A'*B'+A*B'";
}


// Example for a function with 3 variables A,B,C 
generateSumOfMinterms("A", "A,B,C"){

//The result should looks like this
return "A*B*C+A*B*C'+A*B'*C+A*B'*C'";
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
public List<Minterm> completeMinterm(Minterm minterm, String variables){
    List<Minterm> minterms=new ArrayList<Minterm>();
    minterms.add(minterm);
    Minterm m1=new Minterm();
    Minterm m2=new Minterm();
    for (int k = 0; k < minterms.size(); k++) {
 //A AB--> AB+AB'
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length(); i++) {
        boolean varInMinterm=false;
        for (int j = 0; j < minterms.get(k).atoms.size(); j++) {
            if(minterms.get(k).atoms.get(j).variable==variables.charAt(i)){
                varInMinterm=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!varInMinterm){
            varInMinterm=false;
            m1= minterms.get(k);
            m1.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),false));
            m2 = minterms.get(k);
            m2.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),true));
            minterms.remove(k);
            minterms.add(m1);   
            minterms.add(m2);   
            k=0;

        }
    }
    }
```

I used eclipse debugger to find errors, I don't understand, why the atom added to m2 is added to m1 too in the same time, when this line is run:

```
m2.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),true));
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment (if it is, please tag it as such). What have you done yourself so far, and what are you stuck at?

Comment: @ Aasmund Eldhuset: When i ask short, you say explain your question, when I ask in detail, u say it is homework :). No it is not a homework assginment, I just dont have a good approach to realize this algorithm.

Comment: Then, you should state in your post that you need hints for the overall approach (note that your post doesn't actually contain a question).

Comment: That edit doesn't really pose a question that couldn't be inferred from the original. What is you are actually trying to do? Be more specific than 'I want to do this algorithm'.

Comment: I am trying to generate the sum of minterms in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline of a possible approach: First, you should create a more convenient representation of the expression - for example, the expression could be a list of instances of a `Minterm` class, and `Minterm` could contain a list of instances of an `Atom` class, each of which could contain a `char` that tells which variable it is and a `boolean` that tells whether the variable is negated or not. The first thing you should do is to loop through `termsOfTheFunction` and create such objects that represent the expression. Then, you can loop through the minterms, and every time you see a minterm that is missing one variable, you can remove it from the list and add two new minterms with the missing variable. Finally, you can loop through the finished minterms and "print" them to a result `String`.

Class declarations per request and for clarity (using public fields for brevity):

```
public class Atom {
    public final char variable;
    public final bool negated;
    public Atom(char variable, bool negated) {
        this.variable = variable;
        this.negated = negated;
    }
}

public class Minterm {
    public final List<Atom> atoms = new ArrayList<Atom>();
}
```

In `generateSumOfMinterms()`:

```
List<Minterm> expression = new ArrayList<Minterm>();
Minterm currentMinterm = new Minterm();
expression.add(currentMinterm);
```

Then, loop through the characters of `termsOfTheFunction`. Each time you see a letter, look at the next character to see if it is a `´`, and add an `Atom` with that letter and with the correct negation. Each time you see a `+`, create a new `Minterm` and add it to `expression`, and keep going. Afterwards, you can start analyzing the minterms and expanding them.

Edit in response to your code: Looks like you're well on your way! The reason both atoms get added to the same minterm is that both `m1` and `m2` refer to the *k*'th minterm since you say `m1 = minterms.get(k);` and `m2 = minterms.get(k);`. `get()` does not copy or remove an element from a list; the element will still be inside the list. So for `m2`, you need to create a new minterm that has all of the atoms from the old one, plus the new atom.

Comment: this sound to be complecated and abstract

Comment: @AhmedSalah: I am fairly confident that it will be easier and cleaner than working directly with the expression as a `String`. See my edit for some code, but I won't write the entire program for you. Feel free to tell me if you try it and get stuck, though.